# how can i hide my source code in android studio?

Tags: java, android, maven, aar

I have generate my aar library with android studio, and published it to my private repo on github. when I reference my aar lib in other project, I can easilly find my source code, just press ctrl+B(on windows). So, how can I hide my source code?

Comment: I guess code is just decompiled when you view it in Android Studio.

Comment: you can use obfuscation like ProGuard. That's the only way to hide the code.

Comment: Hide a library source code
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42133700/hide-a-library-source-code

Answer (score 0):

The code is just decompiled; Java bytecode is very much equivalent to the original source code. The only way to hide the code is obfuscation; you can use tool like ProGuard (or commercial extended version of it, DexGuard) to do obfuscation.